# Get users birthday from Facebook Graph API

Tags: react-native, facebook, facebook-graph-api, expo

Let me start by saying I see other answered questions with this a similar title but nothing is working for me.

I'm trying to get the users Birthday from Facebooks API, I'm using expo-auth-session.
I can successfully get the users ID, email and name but nothing else.
Here is my code, what am I missing?

```
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
    // clientId: '2877415105738397',
    androidClientId: FacebookClientId,
    iosClientId: FacebookClientId,
    expoClientId: FacebookClientId,
    scopes: ['user_birthday '],
    redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({ useProxy: true })
  });
```

Once I have the access_token

```
await axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/me?fields=id,name,email,birthday&access_token=${token}`)
```

But I only get the `{"email": "email@gmail.com", "id": "123415656565", "name": "Name"}`

I do have app review permissions

**UPDATE, FULL COMPONENT BELOW**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import * as AppAuth from 'expo-auth-session';
import { useAuthRequest } from 'expo-auth-session/build/providers/Facebook';
import { FacebookClientId } from '../config/constant';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { FacebookIcon } from '../assets/SvgIcons/FacebookIcon';
import { Styling } from '../assets/style/styling';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { onSignupExternal } from '../store/user/user.action';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const useProxy = Platform.select({ web: false, default: true, 'android': true, 'ios': true });
const discovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.facebook.com/v6.0/dialog/oauth',
  tokenEndpoint: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/oauth/access_token',
};

export const FaceBook = ({ setLoading }) => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({})
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { user } = useSelector((storeState) => storeState.userModule);
  const clientId = FacebookClientId;
  const scopes = ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday'];


  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId,
      scopes,
      useProxy,
      redirectUri: AppAuth.makeRedirectUri({
        native: 'com.myapp.app:/',
        useProxy,
      }),
    },
    {useProxy: useProxy},
    discovery
  );


  async function handlePress() {
    try {
      const result = await promptAsync();
      if (result.type === 'success') {
        setLoading(true)
        getUserData(result.params.access_token)
      } else {
        // The user cancelled the login or an error occurred. You can inspect the result object for more details.
        console.log('Login failed :(', result);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  async function getUserData(token) {
    let response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,birthday&access_token=${token}`);
    const userInfo = await response.json()
    console.log(userInfo)
    setUserData({
      user_email: userInfo.email,
      user_id: userInfo.id,
      user_full_name: userInfo.name,
      user_ref_id: null,
      auth_system: 'Facebook',
      user_dob: null
    })
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      let updateUserData = userData
      // let ref_id = await utilService.convertMailToAsciiCode(userData.user_id)
      // updateUserData.user_ref_id = ref_id
      return Object.keys(userData).length !== 0 && dispatch(onSignupExternal(userData))
    };
    getUser()
  }, [userData])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user !== null && user?.user_id !== undefined) {
      setLoading(false)
      return navigation.navigate("Dashboard")
    }
  }, [user])

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={Styling.facebookLoginBtn}
      onPress={handlePress}>
      <View style={Styling.googleIcon}><FacebookIcon /></View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  )
}
```

Comment: Does the access token you are using actually include the user_birthday permission? Use the access token debugger to check.

Comment: It looks like im getting just the default email and public_profile. Even though I'm specifying the scopes that I want, It is possible that its an issue with the expo-auth-session API?